# sort files according to name in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a few files stored in my directory according to their dates such as

```
01mar13
09mar13
20feb13
27jan13
```

my problem is I want to sort them such that its arranged as

```
27jan13
20feb13
01mar13
09mar13
```

I have a feeling it should be very simple. Would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction of solving my problem.

Comment: If possible store in yyyymmdd format - problem solved...

Comment: @kojiro: Sorted on date, of course.

Comment: Are the files named `01mar13` or is that some date formatting you sort on? Might be a dumbquestion...

Comment: the files are named as such.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime
import glob

sorted(glob.glob('*'), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%y'))
```

returns a list of filenames sorted chronologically (centuries ignored). And yes, storing files in YYYYMMDD format is a good solution.